# Create Microsoft Graph Subscription in Startup .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create a Microsoft Graph subscription inside of `Startup.ConfigureServices()`, but this requires an async operation.

After doing some research it turns out that .NET does not and probably will never support async operations inside of Startup. At this point I'm just willing to block the thread to create the subscription.

However, I have ran into another issue. The controllers are not set up inside of `Startup.ConfigureServices` even though I am creating the subscription after calling `services.AddControllers()`. This means that the Graph API is never receiving the `200` from my controller which it needs to register the subscription since the controller hasn't been set up yet I'm assuming.

Is what I am trying to accomplish even possible with the current structure of the .NET framework?

The only workaround I've found is to create the `Subscription` object without calling the Graph API, call `services.AddSingleton<Subscription(provider => subscription)`, dependency inject the `Subscription` object into my controller, and then create the subscription by calling the Graph API via an API endpoint inside the controller. Then I must update all of the fields for the dependency injected subscription, since I can't overwrite the object itself with `subscription = await _gsc.Subscriptions.Request().AddAsync(_sub);` (`_gsc being an instance of GraphServiceClient`).

This is what I would like to do:

`Startup.ConfigureServices()`

```
Task<Subscription> subscriptionTask = gsc.Subscriptions.Request().AddAsync(subscription);
subscription = subscriptionTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

services.AddSingleton<GraphServiceClient>(provider => gsc);
services.AddSingleton<Subscription>(provider => subscription);
```

This is my current workaround:

`Startup.ConfigureServices()`

```
services.AddSingleton<GraphServiceClient>(provider => gsc);
services.AddSingleton<Subscription>(provider => subscription);
```

`One of my controller endpoints`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateMSGraphSubscription()
{
    try
    {
        Subscription newSubscription = await _gsc.Subscriptions.Request().AddAsync(_sub);
                
        // Update our singleton instance.
        _sub.Id = newSubscription.Id;
        _sub.AdditionalData = newSubscription.AdditionalData;
        _sub.ApplicationId = newSubscription.ApplicationId;
        _sub.CreatorId = newSubscription.CreatorId;
            
        _graphRenewalSettings.IsActive = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(e);
    }

    return new OkObjectResult(_sub);
}
```

My problem is that I have to call one of my API endpoints after the application has started, rather than having the graph subscription ready when the app has started.

**UPDATE**

I figured out that I need to inject into `Startup.Configure()` `IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime` and then use

```
lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(async () =>
{
    Subscription newSubscription = await gsc.Subscriptions.Request().AddAsync(sub);

    // Update our singleton instance.
    sub.Id = newSubscription.Id;
    sub.AdditionalData = newSubscription.AdditionalData;
    sub.ApplicationId = newSubscription.ApplicationId;
    sub.CreatorId = newSubscription.CreatorId;

    graphRenewalSettings.IsActive = true;
});
```

at the end of `Startup.Configure()` to register the graph subscription with the Graph API once the app has started up. (`sub` and `gsc` are my Subscription and GraphServiceClient objects, respectively, and I inject these into `Startup.Configure()` also)

This is not ideal since I would like to inject an already registered Subscription object instead of updating all of the fields like I do above, but I could not find a better way to do this.

Comment: .NET 5 is already out of support. It was only a single-year "current" version. The long-term support version is .NET 6 which will be supported until 2024

Comment: This isn't a sudden change. The [.NET Core lifecycle policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core) was announced when the first Long-Term-Support version, 2.1, came out.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldve been more clear. I'm using .NET 6 but my Startup and Program classes are set up as they would be in .NET 5, which is why I put it in the title.

Comment: You can create applications using `Startup` in .NET 6. This isn't a .NET 5 feature. In fact, in the latest .NET 7 SDK templates there's an option to generate `Startup` again.

Comment: As for `async` inside `Startup`, you don't need it. It's not *Startup* that needs to asynchronously connect to the Graph API, it's the services and factory methods. Instead of a singleton `subscription` value you can have a singleton SubscriptionService that retrieves and caches the subscription when needed. ` gsc.Subscriptions.Request().AddAsync(sub);` should go into that service

Comment: There are other ways too. Jimmy Bogard created [an HttpClient handler](https://github.com/jbogard/AzureAdExample/blob/main/AzureClient/AzureIdentityAuthHandler.cs) that can be used to generate Azure Identity tokens for HttpClient instances that need to use Azure Identity for authentication

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what I meant was that the .NET 6 docs tell you to just use Program rather than the combination of Program and Startup in .NET 5 docs. I do like your idea of using a service and I will go ahead and start implementing that. So I'm assuming I would just call the service from the `lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register()` function? and this service would be injected with `AddScoped<IService, Service>()`?